# make background green easy as possible

Tags: jquery, html

With jquery, and a super simple html page with hquery loaded, I want to make the background green.

No css is loaded, just literally basic html page and jquery script loaded.

How do I make the background turn green?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The easiest means to achieve this is to use CSS, link a stylesheet with the following declaration:

```
html, body {
    background-color: #0f0;
}
```

If you don't want to link to a stylesheet, use:

```
<body style="background-color: #0f0;">
```

Or use JavaScript:

```
document.getElementsByTagName('body')[0].style.backgroundColor = '#0f0';
```

Or jQuery, if you must:

```
$('body').css('background-color','#0f0');
```

It's worth suggesting that, if you're willing to include the jQuery library<sup>1</sup>, you might want to re-think your desire not to include a proper stylesheet, for a true separation of content and design. Even if you only include CSS in the `head` of the document it's more lightweight, and easier to work with by subsequent developers, than using jQuery, or the `style` attribute, to assign styles to elements.

---

**1** Not a particularly *heavy* inclusion (especially if it's already cached), being about the size of a small-ish image file, but still a weight to consider when putting your pages together.

Comment: +1 for showing the "static" solutions (which often work well enough) as well.

Comment: @delnan, thanks :) ...it's worth noting that the 'static' solutions are, however, pretty horrible for maintenance purposes.

Comment: Note: I was looking for the jquery solution which someone else has above, however the thoroughness of this answers wins the vote.  Thank you.

Comment: @David19801: thank you for the accept, but it's worth re-iterating that using jQuery to assign `background-color` might be overkill, *manipulating* it, yeah, but *assigning* it should really be done with stylesheets. Unless you have a very specific use-case that I don't fully appreciate, or know of. :)

Answer (score 1):

As I came across lot of times with scenarios like yours, in my experience sometimes quick fixes in the HTML (for example inline style) can cause problems and sometimes to change the CSS file or add a new one can cause issues (yes I said that! Sometimes is not so easy as it sounds!), so my solutions is:

If there is just an HTML page and you need a permanent fix then the best thing to do is:

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Document Title</title>
    ...
    <style type="text/css">
        body {
            background-color: #00FF00;
        }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
...
</body>
</html>
```

So why to have the style into the head? Why to not have an inline style? Why to not have a separate css file well the answer is simple!

This is the easiest way to have instant style at your body and make your template extendable. Always when I am writing code, I am having in mind that this will change in the future. Maybe I will change my mind and instead of green, I will have blue. Or maybe at the future I want to copy the same template and have another quick template. Especially when you are changing the CSS through JavaScript can cause huge problems at the future. I did spend lot of development hours to realize that a CSS was changed through JavaScript. This is something that it is not easy trackable. So have in mind these rules:

- CSS at a seperate file **[GOOD]** (extendable, you can cache the file and it can be tracked easily with firebug)
- CSS as style at the head of HTML **[NOT SO BAD]** (You can change it easily and it can be detected with firebug. This is also the best way to make sure that the CSS will load instantly)
- Inline CSS **[BAD]** (It can be detected easily, but in my experience it is just a temporary fix and can cause extendability problems )
- Inline CSS with JavaScript **[EVIL]** (It can't be detected with your firebug. It can't change easily and there is no reason to do it!)

Answer (score 0):

This should do it:

```
jQuery('body').css('background-color','green');
```

Answer (score 0):

This will change the background color to green as soon as the document is loaded:

```
<script type="text/javascript">   
$(function() {
   $('body').css('background-color','#0F0');
});
</script>
```

Answer (score -1):

Inline style...

```
<body style="background-color: #0f0;">
```

You could also do:

```
<body style="background-color: green;">
```